# Why does my Node.js application crash although I'm setting --max-old-space-size?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heap-memory

My Node.js application crashes when it reaches around 6GB of RAM, although I set the limit to 12GB with `--max-old-space-size=12582912` and I got 16GB of RAM.

The crash report shows the following:

```
"javascriptHeap": {
    "totalMemory": 6587056128,
    "totalCommittedMemory": 6587056128,
    "usedMemory": 6475691160,
    "availableMemory": 13410340102832,
    "memoryLimit": 13416914837983,
    "heapSpaces": {
      "read_only_space": {
        "memorySize": 524288,
        "committedMemory": 524288,
        "capacity": 515584,
        "used": 33520,
        "available": 482064
      },
      "new_space": {
        "memorySize": 33554432,
        "committedMemory": 33554432,
        "capacity": 16498688,
        "used": 15158576,
        "available": 1340112
      },
      "old_space": {
        "memorySize": 4832038912,
        "committedMemory": 4832038912,
        "capacity": 4751797480,
        "used": 4741345640,
        "available": 10451840
      },
      "code_space": {
        "memorySize": 1048576,
        "committedMemory": 1048576,
        "capacity": 972992,
        "used": 659296,
        "available": 313696
      },
      "map_space": {
        "memorySize": 536576,
        "committedMemory": 536576,
        "capacity": 519168,
        "used": 244240,
        "available": 274928
      },
      "large_object_space": {
        "memorySize": 1719353344,
        "committedMemory": 1719353344,
        "capacity": 13412045490080,
        "used": 1718249888,
        "available": 13410327240192
      },
      "new_large_object_space": {
        "memorySize": 0,
        "committedMemory": 0,
        "capacity": 0,
        "used": 0,
        "available": 0
      }
    }
  },
```

Edit: Environment info from the report

```
  "header": {
    "event": "Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory",
    "trigger": "FatalError",
    "filename": "report.20190918.213706.2664.0.001.json",
    "dumpEventTime": "2019-09-18T21:37:06Z",
    "processId": 2664,
    "commandLine": [
      "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe",
      "--max-old-space-size=12582912",
      ".\\generate_database.js"
    ],
    "nodejsVersion": "v11.13.0",
    "wordSize": 64,
    "arch": "x64",
    "platform": "win32",
    "componentVersions": {
      "node": "11.13.0",
      "v8": "7.0.276.38-node.18",
      "uv": "1.27.0",
      "zlib": "1.2.11",
      "brotli": "1.0.7",
      "ares": "1.15.0",
      "modules": "67",
      "nghttp2": "1.34.0",
      "napi": "4",
      "llhttp": "1.1.1",
      "http_parser": "2.8.0",
      "openssl": "1.1.1b",
      "cldr": "34.0",
      "icu": "63.1",
      "tz": "2018e",
      "unicode": "11.0"
    },
    "release": {
      "name": "node",
      "headersUrl": "https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.13.0/node-v11.13.0-headers.tar.gz",
      "sourceUrl": "https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.13.0/node-v11.13.0.tar.gz",
      "libUrl": "https://nodejs.org/download/release/v11.13.0/win-x64/node.lib"
    },
    "osName": "Windows_NT",
    "osRelease": "10.0.18362",
    "osVersion": "Windows 10 Pro",
    "osMachine": "x86_64"
  },
```

Comment: We need to know more about your environment. Do you run the node inside of a container?

Comment: @IvanVelichko nope its running on my computer under Windows 10. I added the environment information from the report.